# PyTorch: Expected input batch_size (96) to match target batch_size (24)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, pycharm, conv-neural-network

I tried out PyTorch and wanted to write a program for Gender_Classification. But, I got the error message:
**Expected input batch_size (96) to match target batch_size (24)**
I searched for a solution but I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN,self).__init__()

        self.conv1=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=64,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        self.bn1=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=64)
        self.relu1=nn.ReLU()
        self.pool=nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2)
        
        self.conv2=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64,out_channels=128,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        self.relu2=nn.ReLU()
        
        self.conv3=nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128,out_channels=256,kernel_size=3,stride=1,padding=1)
        self.bn3=nn.BatchNorm2d(num_features=256)
        self.relu3=nn.ReLU() 
        self.fc=nn.Linear(in_features=256*56*56,out_features=2)
        
    def forward(self,input):
        print(input.shape)
        output=self.conv1(input)
        print("1.1: {}".format(output.shape))
        output=self.bn1(output)
        output=self.relu1(output)  
        output=self.pool(output)
          
        output=self.conv2(output) 
        output=self.relu2(output)

        output=self.conv3(output)
        output=self.bn3(output)
        output=self.relu3(output)
        print("3.3: {}".format(output.shape))
        output=output.view(-1, 256*56*56)
        print("Flatten: {}".format(output.shape))
        output=self.fc(output)
        print("Output: {}".format(output.shape))

        return output


def train_model(model, criterior, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs):
    # since = time.time()

    # best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    # best_acc = 0.0

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, num_epochs - 1))
        print('-' * 10)

        for phase in ['train', 'val']:
            if phase == 'train':
                model.train()
            else:
                model.eval()

            running_loss = 0.0
            running_corrects = 0

            for inputs, labels in dataloader_dict[phase]:
                inputs = inputs.to(device)
                labels = labels.to(device)
                optimizer.zero_grad()

                with torch.set_grad_enabled(phase == 'train'):
                    outputs = model(inputs)
                    print(outputs.shape)
                    loss = criterior(outputs, labels)
                    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)

                    if phase == 'train':
                        loss.backward()
                        optimizer.step()

                running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
                running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)
            if phase == 'train':
                scheduler.step()

            epoch_loss = running_loss / len(dataloader_dict[phase].dataset)
            epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / len(dataloader_dict[phase].dataset)

            print('{} Loss: {:.4f} Acc: {:.4f}'.format(phase, epoch_loss, epoch_acc))
```

The output should show the epoch and some other information. Actually, I print out the shape of my tensor but I don't know what's wrong. Here is the error message:

```
input: torch.Size([24, 3, 224, 224])
1.1: torch.Size([24, 64, 224, 224])
3.3: torch.Size([24, 256, 112, 112])
Flatten: torch.Size([96, 802816])
Output: torch.Size([96, 2])
torch.Size([96, 2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\long1\OneDrive\Máy tính\Gender_Classification\main.py", line 209, in <module>
    model = train_model(model, criterior, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler, num_epochs=10)
  File "C:\Users\long1\OneDrive\Máy tính\Gender_Classification\main.py", line 185, in train_model
    loss = criterior(outputs, labels)
  File "C:\Users\long1\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1501, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\long1\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1174, in forward
    return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,
  File "C:\Users\long1\anaconda3\envs\py10\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 3029, in cross_entropy
    return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (96) to match target batch_size (24).
```

Comment: Your input batch size should match your output batch size (both should be 24 in your case). However, for some reason you change your batch dimension in your model to 96 with this line `output=output.view(-1, 256*56*56)`. Generally your model should never change the batch dimension, and this is why it throws the error.

Comment: yah However, I think when I put -1 in there it will automatically calculate the number of rows for me. So I don't understand why it can be 96 instead of 24, can you explain it to me?

Comment: The output dimension of the layer just before the `output.view` is `24 x 156 x 112 x 112` (shown in your output 3.3), this means the tensor has `176,160,768` parameters in total. Now by doing `output.view(-1, 256*56*56)` you are essentially reshaping the tensor from the original 4 dimension down to 2 dimension, with the second dimension being `256*56*56=802,816`. As you mentioned, putting `-1` as the argument tells pytorch to infer the first dimension. This is calculated by dividing the total number of parameters `176,160,768` by the fixed dimension `802,816`, which gives you `96`.

Comment: In case you are still confused, the total number of parameters of a tensor is conserved regardless of what reshaping operation you perform. For example, a tensor with size `12` can be reshaped to `2 x 6` or `4 x 3`, but not `5 x 6` as this creates additional parameters.

Comment: @Steven97102 how is the target batch size being determined though?

Comment: you can pick batch size randomly

Answer (score 0):

when you use this statement:

```
output = output.view(-1, number)
```

you should keep in mind that, the total number of the parameters should be same. so
this statement should be:

```
output = output.view(-1, 256*112*112)
```

Now, it keeps the batchsize and we can calculate the loss.